# Deploying Flask app to Heroku - "Connection in Use"

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm deploying a simple Flask app to Heroku - (first time using Flask and Heroku both). When I try to deploy, I get an "Application Error" and the page tells me to try again in a few minutes. The logs state - the "connection [is] in use", retries a few times and then the worker exits (I can post the logs if that is helpful).

My demo.py file:

```
import flask, flask.views
import os
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "bacon"

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('index.html')


def post(self):
    url = (flask.request.form['url'])
    ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)
    title = soup.title.text
    recipe = soup.find("div", {"id": "recipe"}).getText()
    flask.flash(title)
    flask.flash(recipe)
    return self.get()


app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])

app.debug = True
app.run()
```

My procfile is: 
    web: gunicorn demo:app

If I change the procfile to web: python demo.py, I am able to run the app locally using Foreman but still cannot deploy to Heroku.

Any help is very much appreciated. This is my first time doing this!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. Need to add the following before app.run()

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Now it runs fine on Heroku.